# How to find the maximum entry in large array data file gnuplot?

Tags: plot, gnuplot

There is a data file `data.dat` which contains:

```
1   1   1   2   2   6   1
2   4   1   4   1   7   1
3   1   1   6   1   6   1
4   1   1   8   9   76  1
5   1   1   16  1   1   1
6   6   1   9   1   2   1
7   1   1   7   1   99  1
8   8   1   5   8   1   1
9   1   1   3   1   0   1
10  1   1   2   1   1   1
```

Using `gnuplot` we can find maximum value for a particular column (say 4th column) by using

```
stats "data.dat" u 4
```

My original file has more than 100 rows and columns, it's a large array of numbers. I need to find the maximum value from the entire array (here it is 99). Is there some trick in gnuplot to do so?

Comment: Try `stats "data.dat" matrix u 3`

Comment: @Christoph Works! `stats "data.dat" matrix` works too, i.e. without mention of any column. Exactly what I needed, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the maximum valueof a matrix use

```
stats "data.dat" matrix
```